# If condition fail skip to end of file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

> for (( v=0; v<`t` ; v++ ))
>   do
>   awk '/TRAP-TYPE/{i++}i' $fname >tron
>   if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
>   then
>   echo "MIB file found"
>   else
>   t=$t-1
>   fi
>
> some other commands
>   echo "MIB not in directory"
>   done

When the `awk '/TRAP-TYPE/{i++}i' $fname >tron` fails I want it to skip `some other commands` and reach directly the end of the code and just print `MIB not in directory`.

What can I do to do this? Bash doesn't have goto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just move `some other commands` between `echo "MIB file found"` and `else`.